# how to fix ' Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression'

Tags: arrays, reactjs, jsx

I have used array of objects which i want to render in jsx dynamically

```
packageItems=[
    {
        id: 1,
        image: require('./assets/image1.png'),
        title: 'title1',

    },
    {
        id: 2,
        image: require('./assets/image2.png'),
        title: 'title',

    }
]
```

which i want to render in the same component:

```
return (
 {packageItems.map((packageItem, index) => {
                <div className="card" style={{ width: "18rem" }} key={packageItem.id}>
                    <img src={packageItem.image} className="card-img-top" alt="static website icon" />
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <h3 className="card-title">{packageItem.title}</h3>
                    </div><hr />                      
                </div>
            })}
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly `return` the `jsx` from your `map`

```
return (
    {
        packageItems.map((packageItem, index) => {
            return (
                <div className="card" style={{ width: "18rem" }} key={packageItem.id}>
                    <img src={packageItem.image} className="card-img-top" alt="static website icon" />
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <h3 className="card-title">{packageItem.title}</h3>
                    </div><hr />
                </div>
            )
        })
    }
)
```

When calling `map` from inside a jsx block you don't need to return cause expressions are executed immediately:

```
const Component = () =>{
    return(
        { arr.map(item => <div />) }
    )
}
```

Take a look at the above code:

You don't need to `return arr.map(/*...*/)` cause the array returned from it is already implicitly embedded inside your `jsx` block (remember that `arrays` are valid react's children). But the function passed as argument to `map` also needs to explicitly return the new item of the mapped array. When using one line `arrow functions` the `return` statement is also implicit

```
arr.map(item => <div/>)
```

Is the equivalent of

```
arr.map(item =>{
    return item
})
```

Here you can safely omit `return`, but with functions which takes more than one line (like yours) you need to explicitly `return` the transformation

```
arr.map(item =>{
    return(
        <>
            <span> Foo </span>
        </>
    )
})
```

Comment: Wow! thankss alot.. its been like an hour... It worked like a charm.. but why i dont get it. could you please explain

Comment: Updated the answer